# Using a batch script, how do I count files in a remote folder using a ip list/reference file and output it in a ip + filecount format?

Tags: batch-file

What I want to achieve is have an output file that lists how many files are in a specific folder on a number of different remote machines ie(127.0.0.1  394files).
The issue I'm having is the output file generated only has 1 line in it, the last IP in ip.txt

To try and explain the code below, I'm creating a variable called 'testip' which should match the ip/machine I'm calling from ip.txt , this is created purely for the echo at the end, when I tried calling %%i or %%b at an echo, all that appears in the text file is %i or %b , as if its truncating 1 of the % characters. creating a separate variable (SET testip=%%b) got around that issue.
Next loop, it looks for the IP list in the ip.txt file and performs a count on the \test_scripts\ folder.
Then it should echo the IP it ran as well as the count number.

Any idea where this is going wrong?

Any feedback appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
            for /f "delims=" %%b in (' type "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts\ip.txt" ' ) DO SET testip=%%b
            for /f "delims=" %%i in (' type "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts\ip.txt" ' ) DO (

                            SET count=0
            for %%o IN ('type "\\%%i\c$\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts\*.*" '     ) DO (
            SET /A count=count + 1

)
            )

            echo %testip%       %count% >> output.txt


ENDLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: _"Any idea where this is going wrong"_ Yes, there are loads of issues here, some won't cause errors but still. why do you `setlocal` then `setlocal` again at the beginning. You `enabledelayedexpansion` but never use it? Then for what reason do you `enabledelayedexpansion` at the end of the script? and are you really trying to `type` `*.*` on the remote device? you realise it will try and get content of each file? wy are there spaces between your type commands and the starting quotes and even at the ending quotes?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same method as Gerhards answer but with two modifications. I've set the `remote` variable at the start of the script instead of repeating that on each iteration of the loop; and I'm outputting the IP address, instead of the remote path, with the file count.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "location=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test_scripts\ip.txt"
Set "remote=\\%%A\C$\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts"
(   For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%A In ("%location%") Do (Set "#=0"
        For %%B In ("%remote%\*") Do Set /A #+=1
        Echo %%A       !#!))>"output.txt"
```

This is similar except that it uses the `Dir` command to retrieve the file count. *The `Dir` command can take account of hidden and system files etc.*

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "location=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test_scripts\ip.txt"
Set "remote=\\%%A\C$\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts"
(   For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%A In ("%location%") Do (Set "_=" & Set "#="
        For /F %%B In ('Dir "%remote%" /A-D/D') Do Set "#=!_!" & Set "_=%%B"
        Echo %%A       !#!))>"output.txt"
```

You can easily modify your location and remote paths on lines `3` and `4`, ensuring that the `\\%%A\` section remains unaltered.

*In have not tested either script, nor have I made any attempt at error trapping etc. I'll leave that to you, should it be required*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead. Note how delayed expansion is used. For more on the commands, run them with `/?` switch on cmdline. for instance. `for /?`

Also you will see that command `type` is not used at all.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "location=C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts\ip.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%location%) DO (
                 set "remote=\\%%i\c$\Users\testuser\Desktop\test_scripts\*"
                 set count=0
                 for %%x in (!remote!) do set /a count+=1
                 echo !remote!       !count! >> output.txt
    )
```

Comment: @rubix. No problem. Here is a [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how to thank someone for a helpful answer.